# Updated to Android sdk r15, but now I can't use anything

Tags: android

I'm not sure what I did wrong, but I'll try and give as much information as I can.

Yesterday, I updated a few things in the manager, with one of them being sdk r15. Now, I'm not sure what was updated because I believe there is the sdk 15 and the adt plugin r15. In any case, one of them was updated. I didn't restart and continued to work without any problems. However, today my emulator stopped loading the app I was testing. I restarted eclipse and was thrown this prompt:

> "This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 14.0.0
>   or above.  Current version is 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431.  Please
>   update ADT to the latest version."

Currently, all of my projects have error symbols next to them. I then proceed to click the AVD manager, which I'm given a prompt that says:

> "The location of the Android SDK has not been setup in Preferences."

I go to Preferences and see that the sdk path is pointing to the correct folder. I haven't changed anything so I dont see how the path could be a problem.

What happened? How can I get things working again? Perhaps, the update did not install everything properly?

EDIT:
By the way, I "apply" and "ok" are greyed out in Preferences no matter which folder I choose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Update Manager feature of your Eclipse installation to install the latest revision of ADT on your development computer.<>

Assuming that you have a compatible version of the Eclipse IDE installed, as described in Preparing for Installation, above, follow these steps to download the ADT plugin and install it in your Eclipse environment.

1. Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software....
2. Click Add, in the top-right corner.
3. In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:

   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
4. Click OK

Note: If you have trouble acquiring the plugin, try using "http" in the Location URL, instead of "https" (https is preferred for security reasons).
5. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
7. Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.

Note: If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.

1. When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

### OR

You can launch the Android SDK and AVD Manager in one of the following ways:

> From within Eclipse, select Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager.
>   On Windows, double-click the SDK Manager.exe file at the root of the Android SDK directory.
>
> On Mac or Linux, open a terminal and navigate to the tools/ directory in the Android SDK, then execute: